# How to merge 3 different pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have 3 pandas dataframes as :

```
abc
xyz
```

```
colour
type
pattern
colour
type
pattern
```

```
lenght
breadth
height
area
lenght
breadth
height
area
```

I want to combine the dataframes so that it looks like this :

```
abc colour   length
    type     breadth
    pattern  height
             area 
xyz colour   length
    type     breadth
    pattern  height
             area
```

I also want to export the end result to an excel sheet so how do i do that without making it look messy?

Comment: What do you want the dataframes to merge on? Here is a good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) explaining how to merge the dataframes. Then you will have to perform a `groupby` operation over each sub column type. Also, please add more details (like data samples, what you have tried till now) and specify where exactly you need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first concat second and third df with rows of first df and concat them:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['abc'],['xyz']],columns=['col1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['colour'],
['type'],
['pattern']],columns=['col2'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame([['lenght'],
['breadth'],
['height'],
['area']],columns=['col3'])

pd.concat([pd.concat([df[lambda x: x.index == i].reset_index(),df2,df3],axis=1) for i in range(len(df1))]).drop('index',axis=1)
```